# How to initialized struct with member variable type mapping

Tags: solidity, ethereumj

I have a problem with the below code,  specifically samplestruct2

```
struct samplestruct1 {
    string name;
}
struct samplestruct2{
    string name;
    mapping (int => samplestruct1) s1s;
}

function createSampleStruct2(string name) {
    samplestruct2 s2;
    s2.name = name;
    ...
}
```

`samplestruct2 s2` is giving me a warning : `"uninitilized storage pointer"`

I also tried `samplestruct2 s2 = samplestruct2(name)`, it gives me also an error

Answer (score 4):

Because `s2` is a `struct` being instantiated in the function rather than the contract, solidity will make it a `storage` member of the contract itself.  This is unlike other primitive types which default to `memory` in the local scope of the function. The warning is a prompt to make a proper declaration. Either declare `s2` in the contract or use `memory` to make `s2` local to `createSampleStruct2(string name)`

```
contract c {
    struct samplestruct1 {
        string name;
    }
    struct samplestruct2{
        string name;
        mapping (int => samplestruct1) s1s;
    }

    samplestruct2 s2; // declared in contract storage scope.

    function setS2Name(string name) {
        s2.name = name;
    }

    function newS1(int key, string name) {
        samplestruct1 memory s1; // using memory for structs before commiting to storage.
        s1.name = name;
        s2.s1s[key] = s1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've Got the solution by creating a mapping to hold samplestruct2. now I can initialize the struct using below:

`st3 s3 = s3s[msg.sender]`;d where s3s is `mapping (int => samplestruct2) s3s;`

Comment: @BadrBellaj - I'm a new Soldiity developer.  Is that "where" statement part of Solidity, or just a comment?  I didn't know that Solidity had a SQL style syntax for collection operations.

Comment: this is not a sql query and there is no where keyword.