# How to initialize a mapping of structs with a mappings?

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I have a mapping of a struct, which has a mapping to another struct:

```
uint256 public questionIdCounter;
mapping(uint256 => Question) public questions;

    struct Question {
        uint256 answerCounter;
        mapping(uint256 => Answer) answers;
    }
    struct Answer {
        address answerer;
    }
```

And I'm looking to add a new `Question`, which can have `Answer`s added to it.

```
function askQuestion() public {
        questions[questionIdCounter] = Question();
        questionIdCounter = questionIdCounter + 1;
    }
```

And then people can add answers

```
function answerQuestion(uint256 questionId) public {
        // Add new answer
        questions[questionId].answers[questions[questionId].answerCounter] = Answer({answerer: msg.sender});
        // update answer counter
        questions[questionId].answerCounter = questions[questionId].answerCounter + 1;
}
```

However, when I look at `kbase_questions.questions(0)` I only get to see the `answerCounter` and not the `answer` mapping.

Why is my empty mapping not being initialized?

I've looked at [How to initialized struct with member variable type mapping](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/how-to-initialized-struct-with-member-variable-type-mapping) and [How to initialized struct with member variable type mapping](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/how-to-initialized-struct-with-member-variable-type-mapping), which seem to be the closest to what I'm looking to do, but they are declaring their struct outside the function, which I can't do because I have many structs.

Comment: This may be a debugger problem. Try to deploy a contract and see its behavior on a real network.

Comment: What version of compiler are you using? I think you'll get an error in `askQuestion()` function in `0.7.0`, because of the struct constructor `Question()`. You might have to redesign the structs so that they don't contain a mapping inside.

Comment: Relevant: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/070-breaking-changes.html#mappings-outside-storage

Comment: Ahhhhhh. I'll have to check the version. This might be what's going on, these "silent skippers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After v.0.7.0 and forward, you can't have nested mappings like this anyway.
2. The debugger I was using wasn't showing me the mapping.